# The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty - django+pycharm

Tags: python, django, pycharm, settings

For sure I searched a few posts but none of them helped though.  Even the closest one didn't help too.

I am currently using pyCharm installed django using virtual environment.
As I have tried lots of ways but no luck using pycharm to run the project
BUT if I do it in the terminal by using `python manage.py runserver` the server runs properly though.  Somehow in pyCharm after all the setup, it just wouldn't let me run.  Where am I setting it wrong in pycharm?

Anyways, I am getting this error

`raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.`

my manage.py as some posts were talking about this but I see it's setting up properly though

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "CodingEntrepreneurs.settings")
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError:
        # The above import may fail for some other reason. Ensure that the
        # issue is really that Django is missing to avoid masking other
        # exceptions on Python 2.
        try:
            import django
        except ImportError:
            raise ImportError(
                "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
                "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
                "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
            )
        raise
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

my settings.py (without saying much, I do have the KEY)

```
# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'SECRET_KEYSECRET_KEYSECRET_KEYSECRET_KEYSECRET_KEY'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True
```

`

my folder structure

[image: my folder structure]

my run-debug config

[image: my run-debug config]

my django-framework setting

[image: my django-framework setting]

Answer (score 11):

Since it was a question from 20th of january, I do think it has been resolved already. However, I'd like to share my fix to the same issue.

I ran in into to same issue here. I've been struggling around for a while. Finally it seemed to be an issue with the `Environment Variables`, as shown in your second screenshot (`Run/Debug Configurations`)

I've fixed it by updating the `Environment Variables` path from

```
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=portfolio; <..crop..>
```

to

```
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=portfolio.settings; <..crop..>
```

I had to add `settings` to the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` path.

Comment: the same issues appears if you use IntelliJ Ultimate with python package. Adding .settings to DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE fixes the problem.

Comment: Nice, setting DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE in 'Django console' setting resolved this for me as well. Thanks!

Comment: This didn't help me. However setting the SECRET_KEY in environment variables in intellij config worked.

Comment: @AbhayManiyar The intelliJ's config is probably not the best place to store your secret key and will get you in trouble on deploying / opening project on other computer. If you set your SECRET_KEY properly in your django settings file and your settings file is properly loaded, it should work perfectly fine. What you have done is not a proper solution but a bad work-around imho.

Comment: @Nrzonline I totally agree with you but I was facing error while settings file was loaded and that's why went for this workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like PyCharm doesn't know where your settings file is. Essentially if you ever use runserver & see the secret key error like that, your settings aren't being loaded properly.

In the django config window you've got there the settings definition is a folder/directory. That should be the path to your settings file. `manage.py` has the path defined, Pycharm doesn't.

Also, if you right-click on your project root directory and choose 'Mark Directory As' > 'Sources root'. That'll help Pycharm figure things out for itself. You can also mark a default template dir, or exclude directories.

I'd also recommend using lowercase app (folder) names within the project.

Finally, your project structure looks a little off from the 'standard' that most would be used to. You should probably look to have something like;

```
- CodingEntrepreneurs
-- .venv
-- myproj
--- myapp
```

Then in Pycharm you'd create a project from `myproj`, not `CodingEntrepreneurs`, and `myproj` would be marked as your sources root.

Have a read of this post about project structure; http://www.revsys.com/blog/2014/nov/21/recommended-django-project-layout/

Besides all that, you can specify the settings file to run with by doing `python manage.py runserver --settings=CodingEntrepreneurs.settings`

Comment: I have tried the right click project as root directory too but no luck :(

Comment: @Dora try to specify the settings path; `python manage.py runserver --settings=CodingEntrepreneurs.settings`

Comment: Yes that would work as that's the same as just using `python manage.py runserver` in the terminal. weird...I can see how you mean by structure is different.  This is even MORE weirder, I have like 2 other projects setup the settings totally the same structure I am setting pycharm the same way as the other two projects and been looking at the structure difference and couldn't find any that's why it's bothering me so much :( It is annoying keep on typing `python manage.py runserver` in terminal if I need to restart the server but the worst thing is I can't use pycharm's debug mode :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it turned out I was the problem:

I set SECRET_KEY = 'mysecretkey' towards the top of the settings.py file but didn't delete the Django default further down:

```
# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
```

... so the variable got overwritten every time.

hope this helps whoever is as dumb as me and stumbles upon the same problem